# buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum no such file or directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, github-actions

I have a workflow to do CI and CD work, but the problem is that my jar file, which is compiled and packaged during CI, cannot be found in the packaged folder when it will be built. I think this is because two workflows run in separate work environments, and the operation performed in one of them is deleted after the job is completed. So, my main problem here is that my worfklows do not work synchronously, and the CD must continue from where the CI process ends. By the way, my project is a spring boot project. I hope I could express myself well.[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsyZl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5c3b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTm3g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he0mA.png)

I tried using github artifact, but the same problem persisted. In the photos I added, you can see how I tried to use the github artifact.